# java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection java.net.BindException Address already in use: bind

Tags: java, selector

I am running a long time selector test on the windows7 system on the eclipse console.After 12 hours, so much select.open have been done seccessfully times by times, it,the 'selector.open()', suddenly throws the following excetption:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:125)
at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:69)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(PipeImpl.java:141)
at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(SelectorProviderImpl.java:50)
at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Pipe.java:150)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(WindowsSelectorImpl.java:126)
at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(WindowsSelectorProvider.java:44)
at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Selector.java:227)
at cn.scut.chiu.weibocrawler.job.JobManager.initIO(JobManager.java:55)
at cn.scut.chiu.weibocrawler.job.JobManager.<init>(JobManager.java:50)
at cn.scut.chiu.weibocrawler.distributed.worker.Worker.doCommandJob(Worker.java:80)
at cn.scut.chiu.weibocrawler.distributed.NodeBase.writeOp(NodeBase.java:186)
at cn.scut.chiu.weibocrawler.distributed.NodeBase.selectOp(NodeBase.java:87)
at cn.scut.chiu.weibocrawler.distributed.worker.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:344)
at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:336)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:199)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:67)
at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(PipeImpl.java:91)
... 15 more
```

And my question is that what has happened to the program? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Why* do you keep creating Selectors? Maybe you're leaking them? In any case you should use one Selector for as long as possible, not keep creating new ones.

Comment: Thanks! And you're right. But the program is running on the server end, when a request is coming from the client, it creates a thread to deal with the request and steps of responses... so there will be one selector to one response thread... And I am still wondering if this a proper code logic, could u help me in detail :)?

Comment: Why would you create a thread that uses non-blocking I/O and its own `Selector`? It's madness. Just use blocking I/O. Or *one* thread and *one* `Selector.`

Comment: Thanks 4 answering my question, then i don't really know how 2 use selector, and by this question, I have chosen 'one thread and one Selector' which work well 4 my job!